# Is it possible to derive generalization for this?

Tags: functions, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

If we have an $f(x)=x^2+1$ and we have an iterated function $f^n(x)$ is it possible to derive the formula for $f^n(x)$ after n iterations?

What I was able to calculate is the number of terms this iterated function has after k iterations and that is: $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. However, this formula gives number of terms when the like terms are uncollected. And I was also able to calculate some coefficient of some $x^i$ with the help of multinomial theorem.

I was also able to derive a formula of terms when they are collected. $n=\frac{2^k+2}{2}$ Where k is the number of iterations done.

To answer the question in the comments $f^{n+1}=(f^n(x))^2+1$

But other than that I struggle to derive a formula to find the value of $f^n(x)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure, $f^{n+1}(x) = (f^{n}(x))^2 + 1$?

Comment: So you say 3 iterations gives 6 terms? Might be good to include that as an example,

Comment: updated my question

Comment: @coffeemath do you applying multinomial theorem would help?

Comment: You can just use Cauchy product to get from each expanded iterate to the next, remembering to add $1.$

Answer (score 1):

First off, if $x=0$, then the sequence that is generated by $f^{n}(0)$ is here [OEIS: A003095](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C26%2C677&language=english&go=Search). The sequence originated from the research of the [number of binary trees of height less than n.](http://neilsloane.com/doc/doubly.html). From what I can tell, there are still a lot of questions about this specific sequence.

Perhaps the best way to derive a formula would be to throw this recursion into a [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).